# Why is my jupyter notebook .ipynb file NOT updating when I download it as a .py file despite making changes in the .ipynb file?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have just encountered some very strange behaviour in Jupyter Notebook.  I edited an .ipynb file and downloaded it as the .py file equivalent.  However, when I look at the .py file, the changes have not been made.  It is as if the download as function is referencing an earlier version of the .ipynb file somewhere, but I cannot understand the behaviour.

I have tried renaming the .ipynb file and then downloading it again and it DOES update in the new .py file.  Then I change the file name back to the original .ipynb file name and save it again as a .py file BUT it reverts to the original unchanged .py file.

Any ideas or explanation here for what is going on and how to fix please?  Thanks!

Comment: I would just make sure to save your work before trying to download the file (crtl+S), this creates a checkpoint in jupyter.

Comment: Indeed, I have done this.  The "reversion to an earlier version" style behaviour is bizarre though.

Comment: You say the behavior is in Jupyter Notebook, but it seems it is on your system since you are downloading and then when renaming this reversion happens? You could probably help describe the situation better. Is this on a remote machine so you can look at it there and compare to local? Are you using OneDrive or something that manages your local files?

Comment: HI Wayne, indeed I am downloading and saving to OneDrive (on a local machine, but also in the cloud).  However, it is only happening with one specific file, not others.  The behaviour I described was such that renaming the .ipynb file and saving that as another .py file is fine.  I deleted the originally named files, both .ipynb and .py.  Then renamed the .ipynb file back to the original and save the .py file again.  However, it saves again to an earlier version (I open the .py file directly to check and it does not match the ,ipynb file).  Hope that is clearer.  Thanks.

Comment: I have since upgraded Jupyter Notebook and the problem has gone.  So this leads me to believe it was a Jupyter Notebook issue.  That said, I still want to understand what might have been causing the behaviour in the first place in case it happens again.  Thanks.